# How do I use the AK-47 on CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I really suck at using the AK-47 on CS:GO. I seem to play people who are able to just one-shot me with them.

Is there a trick to using the AK-47?

Comment: You aim and you shoot

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness - Sounds simple but in practice it's all about knowing how the weapon will recoil/spread. James' answer goes into specific detail as to how to learn to use the AK effectively

Comment: The answer from @James is great for spraying an entire clip at an opponent, but what you're talking about is one shot accuracy. The best way to be accurate with a single shot is to be stood still, and with a fair few guns, crouching makes single shots even more accurate. If you are moving when shooting, then you have pretty much no chance of hitting your intended target. The other way to make these shots, is to hold angles with your cross hair where you expect opponents heads to appear. You're set and aimed when they appear, so have a much better chance of hitting these shots.

Comment: @Tanner Hmm you may have a point but I took it to mean that the person is getting head shot, not necessarily they were always getting killed in one shot. The patterns below are meant to help you send as many bullets at someone's head as possible.

Answer (score 13):

All the weapons in CS:GO have a static spray pattern. If you hold down the button and empty a clip the bullets will always come out in the same patterns. How this differs from other games is that it is -not- going to move your whole screen so all you have to do is keep the cross-hair on your target. This is why many people refer to CS:GO as a skill based FPS, you have to learn how to adjust for the spray pattern.

There is a very well written page detailing the spray patterns of all the guns on the [community forums](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=378325692). I will however duplicate the AK47 information here since it is what the question is specifically about

The AK47 Spray Pattern:

[image]

This is the pattern of the bullets and these are found by standing still in the game, shooting the wall, and seeing where the bullets go. In order to send all of the bullets into a single location you need to reverse-echo this pattern with your mouse.

For the AK47 this is the recoil path:

[image: Recoil Pattern for the AK47]

People who learn the patterns can send more of the bullets to where they want, this is how they increase their 'accuracy' and get better chances at headshots as they are now sending 30 bullets in a much smaller location.

Again, I highly recommend checking out the community forums link above, and there are quite a few good series of Youtube videos of people showing how to do this, which ever way helps you learn. Eventually though you should hop into a bot game, aim at a wall and try to use these patterns to get smaller and smaller clusters of bullets.